# Finding irreducible polynomial in finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I would like to find an irreducible polynomial of degree $3$ in $\mathbb{F}_4$, where 
$$\mathbb{F}_4 = \{a+b\alpha| \ a, b\in \mathbb{F}_2, \alpha^2 = \alpha + 1\}.$$ 
I first tried to find an irreducible polynomial of degree 2. Since $\mathbb{F}_4 = \mathbb{F_2[\alpha]}$, we know $f(x) = x^2 - x - 1$ is irreducible since $f(\alpha) = 0$ and its degree matches the degree of the simple extension.  However, when it comes to finding a degree 3 irreducible polynomial, I feel it would be very difficult to argue whether a given polynomial is irreducible. Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: What you say "we know" about the polynomial of degree two with root $\alpha$ being irreducible is false, if the meaning is irreducible over $\mathbb F_4$. The fundamental theorem of algebra says such $f(x)$ has a first degree factor $x-\alpha$ over $\mathbb F_4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deciding whether a degree $3$ polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb F_4$ is actually quite easy.  If a degree $3$ polynomial factors then at least one of those factors must be degree $1$, i.e., your polynomial must have a root.  So a degree $3$ polynomial factors if and only if it has a root.  As your field has only $4$ elements this is straightforward to check.